# Files are locked on ubuntu when copied from my mac or pc

Tags: windows, files, mac, mediaserver

I have installed ubuntu on my old computer, fresh install etc. etc. hope to use it as a central store for media, backups as well as use xbmc on it to play stuff on my TV.

Problem i am getting at the moment is that when i copy any files over onto the hard drives on the ubuntu machine from either the mac or PC they are locked, and the properties state there is no owner and i can't delete them. I have since managed to unlock their properties using nautilus but then when you copy anything new over it again is locked.

Is there a way of stopping these files being locked by default when they are copied over to the ubuntu machine? So i dont have to keep going back in and making them unlocked.

I am very new to ubuntu and not great with all things command line, so if there is a less command line fix for this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal and type:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Then search and select the files you want to open, right-click and properties, then change the permissions :P

Comment: Using `sudo nautilus` is not recommended.

Comment: @juanchitoyoshis Seth is right. The answer used to be to use `gksudo` or `kdesudo` instead, but I think now you're supposed to use `pkexec`.

Comment: thanks for the responses but is there a setting that will change the default properties so than when copied over form elsewhere they aren't locked?

Comment: could the problem be i am connecting to the ubuntu machine as a guest?

Comment: @Seth, could you explain further why this is not recommended? I am having the same problem with (non-system) files that I moved over from my mac. I'd like to make an informed decision on whether to use it or not. Also, I don't know how to use Ask Ubuntu... how do I reply instead of starting a new answer?

Comment: That could be the problem. Try logging in as a standard user or the Admin.

Comment: @Andon See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application I recommend using `gksu` or `sudo -H` when running graphical applications as root.